# Can't wrap my head around Global arrays

Tags: php

I asked about this last night but the answers told me to research global arrays. After spending an entire day trying to solve this I have sacrificed my man card and I'm now seeking help. I have 3 files that work together to echo a variable `$body`. The 3 files are login.php, global.php, and theme.php.

The login file works as expected and displays a message that I'm already logged in when I replace $body with echo, but to incorporate my theme easily and effectively I want to use the variable $body for placement reasons. When I echo $body in the theme file nothing appears. heres a quick example of my files

Login.php

```
<?php 
include('../tools/global.php');

$body="
some scripting here";

?>
```

global.php

```
<?php

function function1(){

   global $body;

}
function1();
print_r($body);

include('../theme/default.php');
include('config.php');


?>
```

default.php aka theme.php file

```
<table border='0'>
<tr>
<td colspan='2'>
<center>bar</center>
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td width='10%'>
hey<br>hey<br>
</td>
<td>
hello
<?php

echo $body;
?>

</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Okay so how exactly would I register the global $body so it will always echo $body in the theme file? I have tried many of different things but nothing seems to work.

Comment: well it looks like your `global.php` is included, and that `function1()` is called before you actually define `$body`

Comment: If you follow the flow of your script - check what's the first occurrence where you declare your $body variable. It's Login.php. And that file is the *last* file in sequence. You invoke global.php first. It includes your theme.php and config.php. At this point you echoed your $body, but it doesn't exist yet. And after this happens, you finally declare your $body. This is exactly the same as if you wonder how come you're not getting anyone to call you on your brand new iPhone that you haven't bought yet :)

Comment: I got it thank god! Thanks so much to everyone. I set `global $body` at the beginning and then I included `$body[path]` at the end. In global.php I set $body[path] to '../theme/default.php and everything is working now OMG this is so awesome I spent way to long trying to do this. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Login.php` includes `global.php` but `$body` is defined in `Login.php` only AFTER  `global.php` was included - that's why you can't use it in `global.php`

If you want to use it in  `global.php` - declare it there!

Answer (score 0):

I think the advice you were given about looking into globals was probably bad advice. Globals are almost never the answer. You are also using them incorrectly. The global keyword allows you to use a global variable (defined outside a function) within a function. It's that simple.  It's much better practice, though, to pass the variable into the function as an argument. When you have stuff that you want to use repeatedly throughout different files, put it in a function in an include file, instead of just the body of the include file.  For instance, in global.php, you have:

```
<?php
function renderPage($body) {
?>
<table border='0'>
<tr>
<td colspan='2'>
<center>bar</center>
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td width='10%'>
hey<br>hey<br>
</td>
<td>
hello
<?php

echo $body;
?>

</td>
</tr>
</table>

<?php
    }
?>
```

Then in login.php:

```
<?php
require('global.php');
$body = 'This is the login page.';
renderPage($body);
?>
```